# Google Maps Api android key

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-maps

I have some trouble testing my Android application which includes the google maps API. The ooficial API example worked just fine but if I copy the code into my own project it keeps saying: "The application has stopped unexpectedly". I looked up the key in the keystore several times  and registered it with google. Even tried reinstalling the SDK. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance

```
05-16 14:31:11.142: ERROR/ActivityThread(662): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-16 14:31:11.150: ERROR/ActivityThread(662): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-16 14:31:12.598: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(542): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
05-16 14:31:12.624: ERROR/MediaPlayer(562): Unable to to create media player
05-16 14:31:05.098: ERROR/ActivityThread(608): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
05-16 14:31:06.538: ERROR/ActivityThread(608): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
05-16 14:31:06.645: ERROR/ActivityThread(608): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
05-16 14:31:12.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715): ERROR: thread attach failed
05-16 14:31:13.698: ERROR/ActivityThread(723): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-16 14:31:13.987: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(723): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
```

Basically my code is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //connect to server

    //get current map scope

    //get media within map scope + a bit

    //init and show map
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //add zoom controls
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 


    //add menu
}
```

Exceptions:

```
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{org.diretto.client.smartphone.android/org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.AnDiretto}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:564)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1626)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.AnDiretto.onCreate(AnDiretto.java:39)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     ... 11 more
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:237)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     ... 21 more
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.setupMapView(MapActivity.java:180)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:279)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:254)
05-16 15:13:05.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726):     ... 25 more
```

XML file line 6 would be:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview" ...
```

followed by other lines of XML-parameters

Comment: Could you please post the following exceptions and some of the code?
The problem must be something else, a wrong API key doesn't cause a Force Close dialog, it simply shows a blank grid instead of a map.

Answer (score 2):

First, do not answer your own question unless you are truly providing an answer. You can edit your question to add new materials, such as your longer stack trace.

Your exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity
```

This is because you are only allowed to have a single `MapView` in a `MapActivity`, and apparently you have two or more.

Comment: Nope, only one MapView in the main.xml, but this is where the problem is... if I remove the mapview from the XML-file the program works...

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the `main.xml` file? Then comment back here so it pops up in my queue again.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are well past this issue, but I had the same issue, here are my notes about the same problem and how I was able to fix it.

[You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216046/you-are-only-allowed-to-have-a-single-mapview-in-a-mapactivity)

[Delete a view and recreate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216470/delete-a-view-and-recreate-it)