# You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity

Tags: android, android-maps

I have a function that shows a map page so I can get the user to choose their current location. But if you run this function twice it crashes the App with the Single MapView in a MapActivity error (i.e. opening that settings view again).

```
public void showMapSetterPage(View v) {
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Settings screen, set map center launched");

    // Set which view object we fired off from
    set_pv(v);

    // Show Map Settings Screen
    setContentView(R.layout.set_map_center);

    // Initiate the center point map
    if (mapView == null) {
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    }

    mapView.setLongClickable(true);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(18);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = lm
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);

    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "The LAT and LONG is: " + lat + " == " + lng);

    point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);

    // mapController.setCenter(point);
    mapController.animateTo(point);
}
```

So I have a button that shows this View and onClick="showMapSetterPage". But if you go back to the settings screen out of the map and click the button again I get this error:

> 03-06 20:55:54.091:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28014): Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   You are only allowed to have a single
>   MapView in a MapActivity

How can I delete the MapView and recreate it?

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete and recreate the map. Setting the content view multiple times should just be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think everyone was a little right, it seams like a flaw in the API to me. I should be able to inflate a view and use the map in it, if I recall the view then be able to delete it or review it again without error.

The easiest workaround was to remove the inflation or setContentView using the xml and going with a dynamic build of the map, then storing that in memory.

**I removed:**

```
// Show Map Settings Screen
setContentView(R.layout.set_map_center);

// Initiate the center point map
if (mapView == null) {
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
}
```

**And replaced it with:**

```
if (mapView == null) {
   // public MapView mapView = null; // Public defined Variable
   mapView = new MapView(this, this.getString(R.string.APIMapKey));
}

setContentView(mapView);
```

This works great and gives me chances to call the map. Thanks for responding everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `setContentView(R.layout.set_map_center);` more than once. 
Why do you need to set the contentView here again? Why not put it in `onCreate`?

Comment: just curious, why don't you use separate activities? Or ViewFlipper (http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here there is another solution that worked for me:

[FragmentMap + ActionBar Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154205/fragmentmap-actionbar-tab)