# GoogleMap Fragment issues

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm converting an application I've written and part of it is a GoogleMap component which I'm trying to put in to a fragment and I'm having issues.

I first had a look at [android-support-v4-googlemaps](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps) and wasn't happy that every FragmentActivity would implement Maps, but having followed these [instructions on how to make a MapFragmentActivity](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b705bbd72d28d000#1a4b01c7d392a08a) I was having problems as now the map would show but on rotating I'd get the "You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity error" - following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216046/you-are-only-allowed-to-have-a-single-mapview-in-a-mapactivity/5217287#5217287) of registering the MapView in code, in the fragment, I got the error that I could only register the MapView in a MapActivity.

So I've now implemented [android-support-v4-googlemaps](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps) and I'm still getting the error on rotation.

I've come to a dead end, and I'm getting a bit frustrated - does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with the `android-support-v4-googlemaps` library. The solution was quite simple after reading carefully how fragments work. Basically, the framework saves the state of fragments on rotation. So, what you need to do is to *only* instantiate your fragments if there is no saved state (i.e. at the first run of your activity).

Here is an example code that worked for me:

```
public class MyMapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        //... init views, do stuff ...

        // Only instantiate fragments at first run
        if (savedInstancestate == null) {
            // Add map & list fragments
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
            AnotherFragment another = new AnotherFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_map, mapFragment, "fragment_map");
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_another, anotherFragment, "fragment_another");
            ft.commit();
        }

        //... do more stuff ...
    }

}
```

In this case I didn't even override the `onSavedInstanceState()`, as I didn't have anything to save. Keep in mind that this solutions *is* using the FragmentMapActivity [library](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps) hack.

I hope this helps.

Comment: works for me.  This is really the best way to handle rotations anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Google released the [Map API Version 2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). This gives you a MapFragment and a [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment). This should solve the problems you had before.