# FragmentMap + ActionBar Tab

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been trying insert a `MapView` into an `ActionBar` `Tab`, but I wasn't able to solve the problem  even googling.

Here is the Main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.action_bar_tabs); 
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, GigLoader.GigLoaderListFragment.newInstance()).commit();

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Geo").setTabListener(this);
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Lista").setTabListener(this);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab1);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab2);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, GigLoader.GigLoaderListFragment.newInstance()).commit();
    }
    else {
        fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, GeoGigLoader.GeoGigMapFragment.newInstance()).commit();
    }

}
```

And here the code of the `GeoGigLoader`:

```
public class GeoGigLoader extends FragmentMapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
}

public static final class GeoGigMapFragment extends Fragment {

    static GeoGigMapFragment newInstance() {
        GeoGigMapFragment map = new GeoGigMapFragment();
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_gigs, container, false);
        MapView mapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        return view;
    }

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

`FragmentMapActivity` is a library from actionbarsherlock.com, and this one extends from a `MapActivity`, so it should work.

The error I get, is the next one:

> `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(954): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
>   E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)`

Anybody know what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to start mapview in the main activity which should extend FragmentMapActivity. Then your fragment can implement the mapview by getting it from the main activity.

Main activity:

```
    mMapView = new MapView(YourActivity.this, MAPS_KEY);
    mMapView.setClickable(true);
    Exchanger.mMapView = mMapView;
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mMapView = Exchanger.mMapView;
    return mMapView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(mMapView != null) {
        NoSaveStateFrameLayout parentView = (NoSaveStateFrameLayout) mMapView.getParent();
        parentView.removeView(mMapView);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Exchanger is a class with a static field with mapview in it.

Comment: But how can i declare the Exchanger mapView attribute??

I have never used the Exchange class

Comment: Exchanger is just a a class I made myself, it's a class with only 1 static field being the mMapView.

Comment: Perfect. Yes I did the same. A Singleton one :-) Thank u so much!

Comment: Why not use a static field in MainActivity instead? to skip the need for an exchanger class?  :)

Comment: That would work, I only used the exchanger to avoid unnecessary references to the main activity.

Answer (score 1):

Google's Maps API Library for Android doesn't support Fragments right now.

Comment: But there are some tricks for doing that. The problem is using action bar + tabs + map

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue changing the *onCreateView* method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_geo, container, false);
    }
    return view;
}
```

where *view* is a *View* object.

Answer (score 0):

I use show/hide methods to avoid creating multiple MapView in a MapActivity :

```
public class TabFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText("List")
            .setTabListener(
                new TabListener(((FragmentActivity) getActivity()), "listFragment", ListFragment.class)));

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText("Map")
            .setTabListener(
                new TabListener(((FragmentActivity) getActivity()), "MapFragment", MapFragment.class)));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view, container, false);
    }

    public static class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private final FragmentActivity activity;
        private final String tag;
        private final Class clazz;
        private final Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class clz) {
            this(activity, tag, clz, null);
        }

        public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class clz, Bundle args) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.tag = tag;
            this.clazz = clz;
            this.args = args;

            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably from a previously saved state. If so,
            // hide it, because our initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (fragment != null && !fragment.isHidden()) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.hide(fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, clazz.getName(), args);
                ft.add(R.id.container_fragment, fragment, tag);
            } else {
                ft.show(fragment);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (fragment != null) {
                ft.hide(fragment);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    }
}
```