# MapView / MapActivity crashes onBackPressed by Child Activity

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapactivity

I am trying to create an informational Activity, which displays a location on google's MapView among other things.  Whenever I navigate through this MapActivity, then click the back button, I get the following error:

"... Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity..."

Things you should know! :

onResume calls my setUpDisplay which initializes my MapView in a LinearLayout:

...

```
        List<Address> geoResults = geocoder.getFromLocationName(formalAddress, 1);
    while (geoResults.size()==0) 
    {
        geoResults = geocoder.getFromLocationName("empire state building", 1);
    }
    if (geoResults.size()>0) 
    {
        point= new GeoPoint( (int) (geoResults.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (geoResults.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
    }
    mapView = new MapView(this, "YOU-NO-GET-TO-SEE-MY-KEY-HERE!");


    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

    mapController.animateTo(point);
    mapController.setZoom(15);


               myMainLinearLayout.addView(mapView);
```

...

I also make sure to call myMainLinearLayout.removeAllViews() on my overrided onPause(), as well as setting variables to null, just to make sure all things are getting cleaned up.

I have also tried to see if, before the mapView initialization, mapView == null -- It Never Is.
Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
-Ethan

--------EDIT:

Here is what I'm doing in my onPause method, in my MapActivity

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{//CLEANUP
    super.onPause();
    myMainLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
    myMainLinearLayout= null;
    mapView = null;
}
```

that's the only method I am overriding besides onResume()

Comment: Did you override onBackPressed? If no, can you post what you are doing in any of the following methods: onPause, onStop, onDestroy?

Comment: I didn't override any other method except onPause, and I've added that above.  Just setting things null and clearing views, ...aggressive memory reclaiming...

Comment: Do you have a MapView being used in your previous Activity? I would try removing the MapView entirely and seeing if the IllegalStateException still persists. If it doesn't, then you can go line-by-line through the lines that touch your MapView to see what's causing the problem.

Comment: I don't create mapviews anywhere else in the code: I only create mapviews in the above example. What is causing the problem is the new MapView line when I hit the backbutton (from the next activity) to return to THIS activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post should help:

[You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216046/you-are-only-allowed-to-have-a-single-mapview-in-a-mapactivity)

Summary: Do not destroy your previous MapView. Instantiate it once in onCreate, and modify it whenever you need to directly.

Comment: Thanks WindyB, I had stumbled upon this answer as well through chance!  I guess I'll have to trust that the Garbage Collector grabs MapView when it takes out MapActivity?