# "Error inflating class" upon returning to application

Tags: android

I have an activity in my android app which displays information, among which is a URL link for a website. I can open it with no problems, but when I click the return button I get the "Unfortunately the application has stopped working" message, and the logcat gives me this:

> 09-25 23:21:58.847: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.example.salefinder/com.example.salefinder.Sale}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #118: Error
>   inflating class

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

EDIT:

Here's the whole error stack:

> 09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.example.salefinder/com.example.salefinder.Sale}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #118: Error
>   inflating class  09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1173)
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-25 23:50:32.367:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-25 23:50:32.367:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-25 23:50:32.367:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3573): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #118: Error inflating class  09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   com.example.salefinder.Sale.saleCreate(Sale.java:71) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   com.example.salefinder.Sale.onRestart(Sale.java:67) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestart(Instrumentation.java:1143)
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4520) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   ... 10 more 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 09-25 23:50:32.367:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     ... 24 more 09-25 23:50:32.367:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3573): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.setupMapView(MapActivity.java:397)
>   09-25 23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):   at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:289) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:264) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:247) 09-25
>   23:50:32.367: E/AndroidRuntime(3573):     ... 27 more

EDIT 2:
At line 71 I have

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sale);
```

and this is activity_sale.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/kontejner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1d7080"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/header" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="@color/border"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/basicData"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/company"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/website"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dates"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="26dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/percentage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showAddress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/border"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="@color/border"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="0z_x3fer_iyOOuWjZ77ZhMt5cYcKovSONgxLeSg"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you post the xml file that you are inflating and also post the whole exception stack rather than first line?

Comment: Sale.java:71 , what do you have on this line, I think you have a setcontentView on this line, can you post the xml of this layout?

Comment: check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216046/you-are-only-allowed-to-have-a-single-mapview-in-a-mapactivity). You are getting this error **You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity** . Looks like you can only do setcontentView only once when using mapview

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating a layout that contains some XML errors in the Activity onResume() method.

Post that XML and we'll try to investigate better.