# Delete a view and recreate it

Tags: android

Is there a way to remove a view that was set with

```
setContentView(R.layout.set_map_center);
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```

If I call this view again then I get an error saying:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You
>   are only allowed to have a single
>   MapView in a MapActivity

Comment: What do you mean by "if I call this view again"? You mean via findViewById ?

Comment: Actually, I think the error is on: setContentView(R.layout.set_map_center);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everyone was a little right, it seams like a flaw in the API to me. I should be able to inflate a view and use the map in it, if I recall the view then be able to delete it or review it again without error.

The easiest workaround was to remove the inflation or setContentView using the xml and going with a dynamic build of the map, then storing that in memory.

**I removed:**

```
// Show Map Settings Screen
setContentView(R.layout.set_map_center);

// Initiate the center point map
if (mapView == null) {
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
}
```

**And replaced it with:**

```
if (mapView == null) {
   // public MapView mapView = null; // Public defined Variable
   mapView = new MapView(this, this.getString(R.string.APIMapKey));
}

setContentView(mapView);
```

This works great and gives me chances to call the map. Thanks for responding everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
((ViewGroup)mapView.getParent()).removeView(mapView);
```

Comment: This does not work, the error is still there. I call it when the settings screen is reloaded and it still has the same error.

Comment: That was just a answer to your question "Is there a way to remove a view" ;-) The code you posted is not enough to see where the error occurs. You should post more code, actually the part that throws the exception.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are actually trying to achieve. Why don't you remove the mapview in the first place from your xml layout if you don't actually need it/want to remove it anyway?

Comment: Here is all the code (mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 creates the exception): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216046/help-you-are-only-allowed-to-have-a-single-mapview-in-a-mapactivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
first inflate the view which you are trying to set in setContentView() by following code;

```
layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.set_map_center, layout);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
    addView(layout, params);
    v.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

whenever you want to delete the view you can simply say layout.setVisibility(GONE)
if you are not able access GONE say View.GONE

Comment: layout.setVisibility(GONE) doesn't delete a view. You need to call parentView.removeView(viewToDelete); - that really removes the view, 'View.GONE' just makes the view disappear for the user, but it's not deleted.

Comment: I am getting errors on VISIBLE, what package do I need to import to support that?

Comment: I am still getting errors on visible, this what Eclipse asked me to do: LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
  layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
  v = View.inflate(getBaseContext(), R.layout.set_map_center, layout);
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
  addContentView(layout, params);
  v.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
  layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);